# Using checked checkboxes in Chrome not working

Tags: html, checkbox

I have some checkboxes on my page. If i write it as checked it will work on FF, but not in Chrome. I tried `checked=true`, `checked=checked` and `checked` simple.

Here one of my checkboxes:

```
<input id="downloadscatids_1" class="input_radio" type="checkbox" checked="true" name="downloadscatids_1" onclick="set_downloadscatids();">
```

Comment: All three should work in Firefox, what version are you using?

Comment: Could you be more descriptive as to what is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okey, solved it!

If you have (mistyped) a table in a table it will not work in Chrome, no matter what method you are using for it!